# Using Mosaic + Orthophotos to create Mosaic produce overlap error?

Tags: mosaic, orthophoto, workflow

I am using Mosaic + Orthophotos from the package from Datem Software. I have 7 photos that I need to generate Mosaic from Orthophotos . I am not very familiar with this software and just learn how to use it. I have read the manual a couple of times but ran without success. Maybe one of you that have use Datem Software and experince how to use it.

Here is the screenshot of what I am tryiing to do...

I created each photo with an add create seam where the overlap is. It is a white line.

[image]

The blue circles I drew are the errors that I need to solve the issue.
Do I need to go back and re-sort these photo in order to overlap correctly ?

[image]